# Network problems running multiple Virtual Box VM

Tags: ubuntu, ip, virtual-machines, virtualbox

Is it possible to run multiple Virtual Box VMs on a desktop computer?

I am running windows 7 as the host OS and have 3 Virtual Box VMs running Ubuntu Server OS.

Each VM works fine on its own when the network is set to bridge.  I have tried the different network settings but so far nothing.  I figure I must be missing something very simple unless of course it can not be done.

When I start up the VMs in bridge mode, I see that there is an IP which I can then hit from the host os.  When I set the network to anything other then that, I am unable to hit the vm from the host.

What I want to do is set up a HTTP vm, Database VM and Confluence VM.  The HTTP VM needs to have its IP exposed to the host.  The HTTP of course will just talk to Confluence and Confluence will talk to the the Database.

Doing this to replicate what we have in a small production system in which we want to upgrade all the software - we do not have any extra boxes to actually build this out at this point so trying to set things up on my desktop.

Comment: It might help if we knew more about what was happening when you try the network with the VM's.

Comment: Posting has been updated based on the comment by Bart

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question: You want three virtual guests that should have routes to each other, correct? You also want the host to be able to route to the guests, right?

If this is the case, bridge connection is exactly what you need. If you are not able to get that to work, please let us know where is it failing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using DHCP on your LAN?

If you do, and you are setting up the VMs to get their configuration from DHCP, ensure that the virtual NICs have different MAC addresses.

If you don't have DHCP on your network, or you do but want to configure the boxes manually, ensure that you use different IPs for each box (and that they do not overlap with other boxes in the LAN or the DHCP pool).

If possible, and esp. if you have control over DHCP, I would suggest using DHCP.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was found at this location:  http://www.orzeszek.org/blog/2010/07/25/fix-missing-eth0-when-cloning-ubuntu-vmware-virtual-machines/